# Rigid Body bake with 2 Torus explodes

Tags: rigidbody

I try to let 2 female symbols falling to the ground, wehre one Ring enclose the other. I have 2 Problems there. The Rigid body bake explode and if i try it with just one symbol it dosnt fall really close to the ground. (The ground is not flat.) I tryied to put the Sensivitiy to 0 but it dont work. Can someone help me?

[image: picture 1]

[image: picture 2]

blend file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NXj04Pd9PH_HzRbQ2JvJfyGz77RLeLum/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the *Shape* to *Mesh* if you want the holes to be taken into account, otherwise the objects will repulse each other:

[image]